# Xamarin.Forms - ListView só exibe se eu clicar na tela.

Tags: c#, xamarin, listview

Olá,

Estou com um problema.

Tenha minha listView, onde traz as informações conforme deve, porém esta informação só é exibida ao clicar na tela. Se não for clicado na tela, a informação acaba não aparecendo.

Alguém tem ideia do que poderia estar ocorrendo?

Desde já, agradeço.

Design/Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="APPDiretoPonto.View.LinhasOnibus">
    <!--ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"-->    
    <AbsoluteLayout>        
            <ListView x:Name="MyListView"            
                        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"           
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        HasUnevenRows="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding nome}" TextColor="Green" Height="32"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Código Fonte no C# da página em questão:

```
using APPDiretoPonto.Model;
using APPDiretoPonto.WEBService;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace APPDiretoPonto.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LinhasOnibus : ContentPage
    {        
        public ObservableCollection<Linha> Items { get; set; }        

        public LinhasOnibus(string sentido)
        {            
            //inicializa
            InitializeComponent();

            //this.IsBusy = false;

            //vai no web service e retorna
            Task.Run(async () => await LoadItems(sentido));

            Task.Delay(1000);

            return;
        }

        async Task LoadItems(string sentido)
        {
            serviceLinha service = new serviceLinha();
            listaLinhas bairro = await service.BuscaOnibus();

            //adiciono o sentidp para buscar a informação e passar como parametro
            foreach (Linha linhas in bairro.linhas) {
                linhas.sentido = sentido;
            }

            //transformo em lista ordernada alfabetica  
            var listaOrdenada = bairro.linhas.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();
            listaOrdenada?.RemoveAll(x => x.nome.Contains("teste")); //removo "teste" que vem do webservice                                    
            //jogo para a list view
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Linha>(listaOrdenada);                    
            MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;           
        }

        async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item == null)
                return;

            //pega o ID do bairro que foi clicado
            Linha x = (Linha)e.Item;
            var idBairro = x.id;
            var sentidoBairro = x.sentido;

            //desmarca Item
            //((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

            //chama a tela que mostra o calendario
            //await Navigation.PushAsync(new CalendarioOnibus(idBairro, sentidoBairro));
            var calendario = new CalendarioOnibus(idBairro, sentidoBairro);            
            await Navigation.PushAsync(calendario);
        }        
    }
}
```

Classe com GET e SET

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace APPDiretoPonto.Model
{
    public class Linha
    {
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }        
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string sentido { get; set; }        
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace APPDiretoPonto.Model
{
    public class listaLinhas
    {
        public List<Linha> linhas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que uma thread secundária não pode alterar a UI, tente substituir seu             `Task.Run(async () => await LoadItems(sentido));` por algo tipo `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{ LoadItems(sentido) });`

Comment: Lucas Miranda, o seu código citado me foi muito útil. 
Porém, tive que fazer uma adaptação por causa do método que acabo chamando em seguida, ficando da seguinte maneira:

--> Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await LoadItems(sentido));

Comment: legal, Renan! para manter o forum organizado responda então a sua própria pergunta dando detalhes do seu processo de solução, ok?